# Assistance migrating from ViewPager to ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm currently working on "Android Fundamentals 04.4: User Navigation", part of Android's Developer fundamentals Codelabs course ([Found here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-training/)).

There are a few outdated things, but I've managed to find the solution after some googling.. however, I'm lost at this one:

```
// Setting a listener for clicks.
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new
                TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
                TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
```

This is started with adding listeners. I have no issues with the
`tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {}` 
However I can't seem to find the ViewPager2 alternative for 
`viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));`

Note: in the lesson it says to use `final ViewPager viewPager = findviewById(R.id.pager);` however both here and in the xml, I've used ViewPager2 rather than ViewPager.

Can anyone point me towards some useful documentation or assist otherwise? Thanks!

Update: Just a extra note, this is "Task 2: Use tab navigation with swipe views" right at the bottom

Update 2: After more searching, I actually came across this: 
 https://developer.android.com/guide?hl=en 
That link leads to a more up-to-date set of Android lessons... If you're someone following the outdated tutorials, try looking at the newer ones :) I've switched over to the new one now, hopefully I won't run into any outdated issues here!

Comment: Did you read the [Migrate to ViewPager2 documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#tablayout)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did, but not well enough apparently... So after re-reading it, I think the TabLayoutMediator is what I need... Is this purely used for naming the tab headers? From what I see, with the implementation shown it would just create 3 tabs called "OBJECT 1", "OBJECT 2" and "OBJECT 3".. How would I implement the correct names? a switch case like before only returned the final header ("COOKING")

Comment: @ianhanniballake new code example:  new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab,position)-> {
            switch (position){
                case 0: tab.setText(R.string.tab_label1);
                case 1: tab.setText(R.string.tab_label2);
                case 2: tab.setText(R.string.tab_label3);
            }
        }).attach();